# The group of all bijections

Tags: group-theory

Let $X$ be a set and let $Y \subset X$ be a subset with $y\in Y$. Let $S_X$ be the group of all bijections from $X$ to $X$. I am given four sets, and I am to determine if each is a subgroup of $S_X$. However, I am not familiar with the notion of a group of functions, specifically a group of all bijections. Feel free to answer any or all of the examples. I should get the idea after a couple. Intuitively, I think a) and d) are subgroups because they map all elements to the same element, which would imply closure, identity, etc.

a.) $\{\sigma\in S_X: \sigma(y)=y\}$

b.) $\{\sigma\in S_X: \sigma(y)\in Y\}$

c.) $\{\sigma\in S_X: \sigma(Y)\subset Y\}$

d.) $\{\sigma\in S_X: \sigma(Y)=Y\}$

Comment: For $b$ and $c$, consider $X=\mathbb Z$, $Y=\{x\in X|x\ge0\}$, $y=0$, $\sigma:x\mapsto x+1$, and $\sigma^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really review the basic notions of group theory, but here's a general idea of what's going on.

The set $S_X$ is a group under composition. Roughly, this means that for $f,g\in S_X$ we have $f\circ g\in S_X$ and that each $f\in S_X$ has an inverse function $f^{-1}\in S_X$ satisfying $f\circ f^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ f=\mathbb{1}_X$.

Now, to check if $H=\{\sigma\in S_X:\sigma(y)=y\}$ of $S_X$ is a subgroup, we can apply the *one-step subgroup test*. To do so, let $f,g\in H$. The one-step subgroup test says that if $f\circ g^{-1}\in H$, then $H$ is a subgroup. To see that this indeed holds, note that $f(y)=y$ and $g(y)=y$ so $y=g^{-1}(y)$. It follows that $(f\circ g^{-1})(y)=f(g^{-1}(y))=f(y)=y$. Hence $f\circ g^{-1}\in H$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $S_X$.

See if you can use the one-step subgroup test to check if the other listed subsets are subgroups.

Comment: When I do this I obtain what I thought I would, mainly because, for example b, there is no unique element of $Y$ that the functions map to. Is this the idea?

Comment: What you said sounds promising. I'd need to see something more rigorous before answering in the affirmative.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right answer. In fact c is also a group if X is a finite set but not in general.

S_X is a group because function composition is associative, the identity map from X to X is an "identity" for it, and bijections have inverses.

You just need to check that the choices are subgroups, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel -- just check that if I have two functions satisfying the given property (e.g. fixing y, for problem a), then so do their composition. Also check that if $\sigma $ satisfies the property, so does $\sigma^{-1} $, and that the identity satisfies the property. (In fact these tests can be collapsed into one step, as in the other answer.)